# Python: Count combinations of values within two columns and find max frequency of each combination

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

My pandas dataframe looks like this:

```
+-----+---------+-------+
| No. | Section | Group |
+-----+---------+-------+
| 123 |     222 |     1 |
| 234 |     222 |     1 |
| 345 |     222 |     1 |
| 456 |     222 |     3 |
| 567 |     241 |     1 |
| 678 |     241 |     2 |
| 789 |     241 |     2 |
| 890 |     241 |     3 |
+-----+---------+-------+
```

First, I need to add another column containing the frequency of each combination of *Section* and *Group*. It is important to keep all rows.

Desired output:

```
+-----+---------+-------+-------+
| No. | Section | Group | Count |
+-----+---------+-------+-------+
| 123 |     222 |     1 |     3 |
| 234 |     222 |     1 |     3 |
| 345 |     222 |     1 |     3 |
| 456 |     222 |     3 |     1 |
| 567 |     241 |     1 |     1 |
| 678 |     241 |     2 |     2 |
| 789 |     241 |     2 |     2 |
| 890 |     241 |     3 |     1 |
+-----+---------+-------+-------+
```

The second step would be marking the highest value within *Count* for each *Section*. For example, with a `True/False` column like this:

```
+-----+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| No. | Section | Group | Count |  Max  |
+-----+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| 123 |     222 |     1 |     3 | True  |
| 234 |     222 |     1 |     3 | True  |
| 345 |     222 |     1 |     3 | True  |
| 456 |     222 |     3 |     1 | False |
| 567 |     241 |     1 |     1 | False |
| 678 |     241 |     2 |     2 | True  |
| 789 |     241 |     2 |     2 | True  |
| 890 |     241 |     3 |     1 | False |
+-----+---------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The original data frame has lots of rows. That is why I'm asking for an efficient way because I cannot think of one.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at `transform`

```
df['Count']=df.groupby(['Section','Group'])['Group'].transform('size')
df['Max']=df.groupby(['Section'])['Count'].transform('max')==df['Count']
df
Out[508]: 
    No  Section  Group  Count    Max
0  123      222      1      3   True
1  234      222      1      3   True
2  345      222      1      3   True
3  456      222      3      1  False
4  567      241      1      1  False
5  678      241      2      2   True
6  789      241      2      2   True
7  890      241      3      1  False
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed!

Comment: @MaMo yw~ :-) happy coding

Comment: this would be perfect, except I get `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'Group'` is this the version of Pandas I am using?

Comment: @Clumsycat ha `df['Count']=df.groupby(['Section','Group'])['Group'].transform('size')`